# How can I test a URL is SSL secured

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ssl, web-applications

I'm new to IT industry. Test scenario is like I need to test whether my application's login page is SSL secured or not?

In general sometime we used to visit some websites where it shows a pop-up for SSL security. So I need to test the same scenario in my application.

I have small web application where I have `login.html` page. Basically, I'm able to start my web application using Maven and server used is Tomcat. Command I'm using to start is `mvn tomcat7:run` and URL using `http://localhost:8080/login.html`. It works perfectly.

But I want to change my URL from `http` to `https` and when I access my URL, i.e to `https://localhost:8080/login.html`, then it should pop-up with SSL security alert and I should accept it.

If my question is still not clear then feel free to comment.

After searching on net I have done some workarounds but its not working out. What I have tried:

#### My HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login App</h1>
<div id="emptyDiv"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
<!--container start-->
<div id="container">
  <div id="container_body" style="background-color:#BBD700;float:center;">
  <!--Form  start-->
    <div id="form_name">
      <div class="firstnameorlastname">
<form >
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <div id="errorBox"></div>
         First Name :   <input  id="firstName" type="text" name="Name" value="" >
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         Last name : <input  id="lastName" type="text" name="LastName" value="" >

      </div>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div id="email_form">
        Email Id: <input style="position:right" type="text" name="Email" value="" >
      </div>
      <input id="sub_form" type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form>
    </div>
    <!--form ends-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--container ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

#### web.xml

```
<pre><code><!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC <span style="color: red;">"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"</span> <span style="color: red;">"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"</span>>
<web-app>
           <!--   <security-constraint>
             <web-resource-collection>
                 <web-resource-name>MyEducationApp</web-resource-name>
                 <url-pattern>/login.html</url-pattern>
              </web-resource-collection>
              <user-data-constraint>
                 <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
              </user-data-constraint>
             </security-constraint>

               <security-constraint>
                  <web-resource-collection>
                     <web-resource-name>Non-SecureResource</web-resource-name>
                     <url-pattern>/login.html</url-pattern>
                  </web-resource-collection>
                  <user-data-constraint>
                     <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
                  </user-data-constraint>
               </security-constraint> -->

  <display-name>Login WebApp</display-name>
</web-app>
</span></code></pre>
```

#### Maven Plugin used

```
    <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>https://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>localhost</server>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>aRfalah</password>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat7-run</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-war-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <fork>true</fork>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat7-shutdown</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: The browsers only accepts the valid certificates, that are signed by a certificate authority (VeriSign for example).

Comment: @traianus : Thanks for replying . How can i make it ?
It is not something that i can do in HTML page or web-application to make it done ?

Comment: It depends. If you want to publish your site on the internet (so that everyone can use it), than have to buy a certificate from one of the CA's and you need a fix IP. If it is just for personal use, than you can import your certificate into yours browser's certificate store to mark it as trusted. PKI is not an easy topic, you can read more at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure)

Comment: Thanks but its just for a personal use. I have to test this URL as a SSL trusted page. How can i import certificate into my browser ?

Comment: In firefox, you can add your certificate easily on the error page. See [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/929298), how.

Comment: Hey ...i have test case where i have to test on my local machine running my application locally .Any changes in web.xml? Because i have read somewhere that it is possible without explicitly making changes to browser.

Comment: @traianus Re _"than have to buy a certificate from one of the CA's"_ - That's not (completely) true. 1. [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) offers 1-year SSL/TLS + S/MIME for free. 2. You can easily create your own certificates with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) (thus being your own CA) and associate this certificate with your `https://` site. If your visitors accept your certificate in the dialog that pops up in their browser it is stored in their browser's certificate store and the dialog will not appear again until the certificate's expiration date is reached.

Comment: Check the hostname on commonName certificate attribute. Must be equals to URL hostname.

Comment: What exactly error present on pop-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSL/TLS encryption for your web site is nothing you can do in your web application. It's done via your web server's configuration.

See [Apache Tomcat 7, SSL Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

---

Additional info (repeated from my comment to the OQ, since comments are not that prominent and editable):

You don't have to buy a certificate from one of the [certification authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) to obtain a certificate.

1. <s>[StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) offers 1-year SSL/TLS + S/MIME for free.</s> <s>[On a different domain](https://www.startcomca.com/) they offer now:</s>

   No offer any more:

   > ## Notice to all StartCom subscribers
   >
   > StartCom CA is closed since Jan. 1st, 2018 that don’t issue any new certificate from StartCom           name roots.
   > If you want to buy trusted SSL certificate and code signing certificate, please visit https://store.wotrus.com.
   > If you want to apply free email certificate, please visit https://www.mesince.com to download MeSince APP to get free email certificate automatically and send encrypted email automatically.

   But there may be other companies meanwhile.
2. You can easily create your own certificates with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) (thus being your own CA) and associate this certificate with your `https://` site. If your visitors accept your certificate in the dialog that pops up in their browser it is stored in their browser's certificate store and the dialog will not appear again until the certificate's expiration date is reached.

Comment: He hasn't said anything about using Apache HTTPD.

Comment: @EJP I wrote _"for instance"_ exactly because of that. I'd love to hear how I can improve my answer.

Comment: @EJP Do you have no hint for me?

Comment: He's using Tomcat. Write an answer about Tomcat. Surely you don't need a hint about that?

Comment: @EJP Thx, that's the kind of reply I was expecting. I adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why the remaining downvote? Is there still something wrong in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to do:

1. Generate a self signed certificate and install the same in Tomcat (Gerold Broser's post has the link)
2. By default, the SSL port is disabled in Tomcat, enable it (same link as bove)
3. Change your URL to `https://local_host:8443/login.html` (default SSL port for Tomcat)
4. Make the request through your browser, you should see a page/message, depending on the browser, telling you that the certificate is not OK

If you want this page to be only accessed through SSL, look at Tim Funk's post and edit the `web.xml` of the application.

Answer (score 3):

The normal practice is to check via request.isSecure() whether the request came in via https or not. If not then send a redirect to the browser to the same URL but prefixed with https protocol.

Here is an example servlet filter to do this:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    if (!request.isSecure()) {
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      String target = "https://" + request.getLocalName() + servletRequest.getRequestURI();
      servletResponse.sendRedirect(target);
      return;
    }
    // tell the browser to use only https for accessing this domain for the next 30 days
    servletResponse.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=" + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // not needed
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    // not needed
  }

}
```

To enable the filter globally add the following to you web.xml:

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The line `servletResponse.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", ...` is optional. If you put it into the code, your browser will never try to connect to http again for the next 30 days but will use https itself. That happens if your browser supports the [HSTS standard RFC6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797). That makes sense if your application should be accessible via https solely. However, I think it is only possible with the standard https port 443. See next.

There is a tiny pitfall in your current tomcat configuration. It is not possible to run http and https on the same port. You need to have two separate connectors one for http and one for https.

To make this happen add to the maven tomcat plugin configuration:

```
<!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
 . . .
```

You also need to add the correct protocol for the redirect target in the SecurityFilter code (or make it an parameter):

```
      String target = "https://" + request.getLocalName() + ":8443" + servletRequest.getRequestURI();
```

The port 8080 and 8443 are only for experimental local web servers, real applications should be on port 80 and 443.

That's it. Have fun and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

To require HTTPS and have your servlet engine automatically redirect to https, you are on the right track with transport-guarantee

So you will probably want

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

The above will only redirect /login.html for your webapp to https. Add more url-pattern as needed.

More details: 
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Security#Q4 and 
http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-user&m=104951559722619&w=2

Comment: Hey .. its not working out... Showing "SSL Connection Error" on the page.

Answer (score 2):

From the original question above:

> Command I'm using to start is `mvn tomcat7:run` and URL using
>   `http://localhost:8080/login.html`. It works perfectly. But i want to
>   change my URL from `http` to `https` and when I access my URL i.e
>   `https://localhost:8080/login.html`

Are you sure about `'http://localhost:8080'` and `'https://localhost:8080'`?

This basically means that you are requesting both SSL and non SSL traffic from same port. Normally Tomcat does HTTP from 8080 and HTTPS from 8443.

Most of the answers here would work for you but first be sure to see if you have enabled the SSL connector in `server.xml`.